# DMARC and Postfix delivery reports

Tags: postfix, spf, dkim, dmarc, rspamd

I successfully set up DMARC, DKIM and SPF for my mailserver's domain, but delivery reports created by Postfix fail the DKIM/SPF tests.

The headers of regular messages (sent via my mailserver)  look like this:

````
Authentication-Results: posteo.de; dmarc=pass (p=quarantine dis=none) header.from=mail.my.domain
Authentication-Results: posteo.de; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=my.domain
Authentication-Results: posteo.de;
        dkim=pass (2048-bit key) header.d=mail.my.domain header.i=@mail.my.domain header.b=FGiVXFOU;
        dkim-atps=neutral```
````

Delivery reports have these headers:

```
Authentication-Results: posteo.de; dmarc=fail (p=quarantine dis=none) header.from=mail.my.domain
Authentication-Results: posteo.de; spf=tempfail smtp.helo=mail.my.domain
```

The Authentication-Results DKIM header is missing as there is no DKIM signature (I use rspamd as an `smptd_milter` to sign messages), and the SPF authentication result refers to `smtp.helo` instead of `smtp.mailfrom`. Is there any way to configure Postfix such that the delivery reports a) are DKIM-signed and b) contain an `smtp.mailfrom` header to pass the SPF test?

**Update:** jnrcorp asked the same question [5 years ago](https://serverfault.com/questions/931890/postfix-managing-subdomain-dmarc-dkim-and-spf-when-bounce-emails-come-from-th) (sorry), and the answer to a) is an addition to Postfix's `main.cf` (`internal_mail_filter_classes = bounce`), but b) remains unsolved – although there is an SPF entry for my `mail.my.domain`, SPF fails. Could this be caused by the circular MX entry:

```
mail.my.domain 60 IN MX 10 mail.my.domain
```